# Is Cambodia safe enough to live, even with the political unrest?

Tags: holidays, cambodia

I'm looking to move to Cambodia for a few years, and I was wondering if there is any political unrest there that I should know about?

Answer (score 9):

Cambodia is not a first-world country, but for many people that's half the appeal.

I have lived in Thailand for the last ten years (talking of unrest!), and I have heard from lots of people who have lived here and then gone on to move to Cambodia simply because it reminds them of what Thailand "used to be like".

Most of the countries in this region (think: Thailand, Cambodia, Laos, Burma/Myanmar, Vietnam) are considered by some to be 'developing' countries, and some are more developed than others in some contexts. This is worth mentioning because to some, sitting in a small fishing village by the side of a huge lake or living a slow life on a tropical beach, would be like living in paradise - whereas other people would not be happy without a high-speed always-on Internet connection and the ability to buy the latest tech goods.

Having said all that, life in this region is relatively inexpensive for the essentials, food is amazing and cheap (local food, that is. Western-style food is expensive, where available), and accommodation similarly inexpensive. Longer-term visas are significantly easier to come by than they are in Thailand.

As for unrest in Cambodia, I have not heard of any except in the areas surrounding disputed temples on the Thai border - avoid those areas.

From people I have known who went to live in Cambodia (usually to Phnom Penh), they say life is good there.

- If you are intending to work there, it's not usually as simple as saying "I want a job" and going to interviews.
- If you don't intend to work there, have a reliable income available for a few years. Plan your budget carefully and be well aware of unplanned surprises and "taxation".